# Custom Template page not loading get_header() correct?

Tags: templates

I'm currently working on creating my own templates with custom content to my wordpress site.

But I'm now struggling with getting the get_header(); function to work?

THIS IS WHAT I'M CALLING

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Register fangst
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Salient
* @since Salient-child
*/
get_header(); ?>

<?php 
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
?>      
<h3>DU er ikke logget ind</h3>
<h4>så du kan ikke registre nogle registreringer</h4>
<a href="riverfisher/login">login her</a>

<?php   } else {
?>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php

global $wpdb;

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$time = trim ( $_POST['dato'] );
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'file-upload', $_POST['billedeURL'] );
$attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
$fiske_vaegt = $_POST['fiske_vaegt'];
$fiske_laengde = trim( $_POST['fiske_laengde'] );

$redskabsID = absint( $_POST['reg_redskabs_id'] );
$koenID = absint( $_POST['reg_koen_id'] ); 
$fiskID = absint( $_POST['reg_fisk_id'] );
$crID = absint( $_POST['reg_cr_id'] );
$laksID = absint( $_POST['reg_laks_id'] );  


$registrering = $wpdb->insert( 
$wpdb->prefix . 'registreringer',
    array(
        'reg_id'            => '',
        'dato'              => $time,
        'billedeURL'        => $attachment_url,
        'fiske_vaegt'       => $fiske_vaegt,
        'fiske_laengde'     => $fiske_laengde,
        'reg_user_id'       => $current_user->ID,
        'reg_redskabs_id'   => $redskabsID,
        'reg_koen_id'       => $koenID,
        'reg_fisk_id'       => $fiskID,
        'reg_cr_id'         => $crID,           
        'reg_laks_id'       => $laksID  
        ),
    array(
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%f',
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%d'
        )
    );

}
?>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Registering af din fangst</h3>
    <p><label><strong>længden</strong></label></p>
    <p><input type="number" name="fiske_laengde" id="fiske_laengde" />cm</p>
    <p><label><strong>vægten</strong></label></p>
    <p><input type="number" step="any" placeholder="vægt i kg f.eks. 12.3" name="fiske_vaegt" id="fiske_vaegt" />kg</p>
    <p><label><strong>Vælg billede:</strong></label></p>
    <p><input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload"></p>
    <p><label><strong>dato</strong></label></p>
    <p><input type="date" name="dato" value="
<?php  
    $time = new DateTime;
    echo $time->format("d-m-Y");
?>"/>
    </p>
    <p><label><strong>Fangst udstyr</strong></label></p>
<?php 

    $redskab = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_redskaber`" );

    foreach ( $redskab as $redskaber ) 
    {
        echo sprintf(
        '<label><input type="radio" name="reg_redskabs_id" value="%s"> %s</label><br>',
        esc_attr( $redskaber->redskabs_id),
        $redskaber->redskabs_navn
        );
    }
?> 
    <p><label><strong>Vælg fiskeart</strong></label></p>
<?php 

    $fisk = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_fiskearter`" );

    foreach ( $fisk as $valgfisk ) 
    {
        echo sprintf(
        '<label><input type="radio" name="reg_fisk_id" value="%s"> %s</label><br>',
        esc_attr( $valgfisk->fisk_id),
        $valgfisk->fiske_navn
        );
    }
?> 

    <p><label><strong>Hvilket køn har fisken</strong></label></p>
<?php 

    $koen = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_koen`" );

    foreach ( $koen as $valgkoen ) 
    {
        echo sprintf(
        '<label><input type="radio" name="reg_koen_id" value="%s"> %s</label><br>',
        esc_attr( $valgkoen->koen_id),
        $valgkoen->koen
        );
    }
?> 

    <p><label><strong>Catch / release</strong></label></p>
<?php 

    $cr = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_cr`" );

    foreach ( $cr as $valgcr ) 
    {
        echo sprintf(
        '<label><input type="radio" name="reg_cr_id" value="%s"> %s</label><br>',
        esc_attr( $valgcr->cr_id),
        $valgcr->cr_type
        );
    }
?>  
            <p><label><strong>Vælg en lakseplads</strong></label></p>
            <select name="reg_laks_id">
                <option disabled selected value> -- Vælg en lakseplads -- 
</option>
<?php 

    $lakseplads = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_laksepladser`" );

    foreach ( $lakseplads as $valgplads ) 
    {
        echo sprintf(
        '<option value="%s"> %s</option>',
        esc_attr( $valgplads->laksepladser_id),
        $valgplads->laksepladser_navn
        );
    }
?> 
    </select><br>
    <button type="submit" name="btnregister" class="button" >Submit</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit" />
    <?php 
}
            echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
exit;
?>
    </form>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

As you can see it seems like something is going on but the little AJAX loading icon just keeps spinning for me ? 
[image: Screenshot]

Do you need to know anymore information to help me with this ?

EDIT:

page.php looks like this:

```
<?php 

get_header(); 
nectar_page_header($post->ID); 

//full page
$fp_options = nectar_get_full_page_options();
extract($fp_options);

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you included the footer? Loading overlays are controlled by JS, which is probably output in the footer of your theme.

Comment: Yes i have unfortunately.. any other suggestions? :)

Comment: look what is the file `page.php` of the theme and you can probably use this as a base for your template/

Comment: I've tried to copy it but it still keeps on loading that icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the exit; call on line 176, does it load? It seems that the footer.php file will never be loaded because you are exiting before reaching that file.

Comment: Yes that did the trick. Oh I'm feeling so stupid. :)

Answer (score 1):

First turn on debuggin by dropping the following code in your wp-config.php file

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

and see if any errors or warning do get displayed.

Moreover it is a good practice to not close the php tag at he end of the file. Try that too.

Comment: Okay if I remove all my custom code the header and footer loads. BUT my custom code loads find without the header and footer? hmm I'm putting my code in the question

Comment: Removing that exit should have helped as mentioned above.